# Scrollview with a scrollview inside, the father scrollview doesn't scroll when softkeyboard appears

Tags: android, scrollview

I am having problems with scroll views..
I have a scrollview  that occupies all the display; inside it I have a header, footer and scroll area; in this scroll area, I have some edittext, checkboxes, and spinners. You can check the code for the layout file below.
When activity is launched, the user can see the header and some of the content inside the child scroll. When I try to scroll down the child scrollview, there is a part where I can't view the rest because of the keyboard. It should be possible to scroll down the father scroll in order to view the rest of the fields inside the child scroll, but the father scroll doesn't move...

I have set `windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` because, when the keyboard appear, I want to maintian the same display and try to use the father scroll to reach the footer. 
I have tried to set softinput mode to adjustresize, but this gives me a small area to view the content inside the child scroll.
Is it possible, or should I set to ajustresize and scale down a bit the header and the footer so that the user has more are to see the content inside the child scroll?

Here is the xml for the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/sc1"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout 

android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#fff"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<LinearLayout 
   android:id="@+id/top"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
   android:background="@layout/gradient">

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/optiserlogo"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_margin="10dp"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:src="@drawable/optiser" />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/bottom"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_saudevisual"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_marginRight="-4.5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-4.5dp"
        android:textSize="10dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/saude_visualoff"
         android:background="#fff"
        android:text="Saúde Visual" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_myoptiser"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" 
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_marginRight="-4.5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-4.5dp"
        android:textSize="10dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/myoptiseron"
       android:background="#fff"
        android:text="myOptiser" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_empresa"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-4.5dp"
        android:text="Empresa"
        android:textSize="10dp"
           android:drawableTop="@drawable/empresaoff"
         android:background="#fff"
        />
 </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout 
 android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_below="@id/top"
   android:layout_above="@id/bottom"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#C0C0C0"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/voltar"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"

            android:background="@drawable/menu_anterior" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/menuprincipal"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_principal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Liquidos"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </RelativeLayout>


        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
           >

            <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
           android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner1"
             android:singleLine="true"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText1" />



        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
            android:ems="10" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
            android:text="Email"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ems="10" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
            android:ems="10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/spinner1"
            android:text="Contacto"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText6"
            android:text="Finalizar Encomenda" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox1"
             android:textColor="#000"
            android:text="Novo Paciente" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2"
            android:text="Entidade"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Obs"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="Nome"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
            android:text="Qnt"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"

            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
            android:text="Entidade"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
            android:text="Nome"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText7"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/checkBox2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:ems="10" />

        </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>




   </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

in the activity i have added this code...

```
ScrollView sc = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sc1);
    ScrollView sc1 = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);

    sc.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {



        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            findViewById(R.id.scrollView1).getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
             String tag="ssss";
            Log.v(tag,"PARENT TOUCH");
            return false;
        }
        });
        sc1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {

        // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of
        // child view
             String tag="ssss";
                Log.v(tag,"chield TOUCH");
        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return false;
        }
        });
```

It's detecting the father and the child, but the father scroll doesn't scroll when the keyboard appears...

Answer (score 0):

by using `windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` you lose focus on the window when keyboard appears you will not be able to scroll.

try this not sure if its work but not hurt to try this solution.

inside your activity onCreate()

add this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

your manifest
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan"